# Pass parameter from Primefaces sheet to backing bean

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I want to pass parameters from primefaces sheet column to jsf backing bean like below.

```
 <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="HTS Chapter" value="#{material.htsChapter}" colWidth="100"
                                                rendered="true"
                                                colType="dropdown"
                                                readonlyCell="#{!itemActionsManagedBean.authCheckForEditForHtsChapter(material.country)}"
                                                selectItems="#{itemActionsManagedBean.getMapItemsForHtsChapter(material.country)}"/>
```

I can pass parameters via readonlyCell attribute. But with selecitems it doesnt pass parameters to backing bean. Its always passing null for selectitems. My scope is @ViewScoped.

JSF: 2.2.1, PrimeFaces: 12.0.0, PrimeFaces Extensions: 12.0.5

Comment: It should work the same way both methods do an `eval` which should just run evaluate the EL expression.

Comment: @Melloware selectitems calling only once while having multiple rows and readonlycell works for every row one by one. selectitems also not getting passed parameters. did you try on your side

Comment: @Melloware When sheet exist in dialog its calling only once selectitems method with null parameter passed

Comment: Answered below.

Answer (score 1):

SelectItems is NOT called per row its called once for the whole column and ReadOnly is evaluated per row that is the difference. SelectItems cannot be different per row which for performance is why its called only once so NULL is expected as you are not in "context" of a row.  So `material.country` is NULL when SelectItems is called because `material` is your ROW which is not even evaluated yet.